# How can I calculate it by applying a weight based on the number of tests to the MTTFB change rate?

Tags: math, data-analysis

First of all, I am collecting and checking test indicators using nGrinder. The most important indicator among them is MTTFB(Mean-Time To First Bytes). This is because it is believed that the safety of the server can be confirmed depending on how STABLE MTTFB is. I am measuring the MTTFB change rate as one of the ways to check this STABLE. For example, something like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfGaG.png)

Change rate = ( |(04:41:18.MTTFB) - (04:41:20.MTTFB)| + |(04:41:20.MTTFB) - (04:41:22.MTTFB)| + ... )/ totalColumnNumber

However, if you look closely, you can see that MTTFB is calculated over 2 seconds, and the number of **tests counted** during this time also exists. In that case, when calculating the rate of change of MTTFB, it was thought that applying weights according to the number of tests would provide a more accurate figure.

How can I calculate it by applying a weight based on the number of tests to the MTTFB change rate?